# Cannot switch signers with ethers.js for a contract interaction using Hardhat

Tags: ethereum, ethers.js, hardhat

Hardhat specifies that to use a different account for contract interactions you should use the `connect()` method, passing it a Signer, as such:

```js
const [owner, addr1] = await ethers.getSigners();
/* ... */
await greeter.connect(addr1).setGreeting("Hello!");
```

Where `greeter` is the contract instance.

However, when I use a Signer as they specify to, I get the following error:

> Error: invalid address or ENS name (argument="name", value="<SignerWithAddress 0x59F...34C>", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.6.0)

The internet says to use an address, such as [this issue](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/1051) suggesting to use something like `addr1.address`. But when I do, the following error results:

> VoidSigner cannot sign transactions (operation="signTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=abstract-signer/5.6.0)

How can I switch signers/accounts when making contract calls with ethers.js and Hardhat?

Comment: It seems that you are passing just the address string - not the whole `Wallet` object that you got from `getSigners()`, to the `connect()` function. Can you verify that e.g. with `console.log()` before using the `connect()` function?

Answer (score 7):

The error you get is because you are not passing in the full address object.
Specifically, I get your exact error when I do this:

**This does not work, but reproduces your error:**

```js
[deployer, account1] = await ethers.getSigners();
address1 = account1.address;
/* ... */
await greeter.connect(address1).setGreeting("Hello!");
```

**This works, however:**

```js
[deployer, account1] = await ethers.getSigners();
/* ... */
await greeter.connect(account1).setGreeting("Hello!");
```

Notice that we do *not* call ".address" on account1 in the second example.

Comment: This is exactly what his code is that is producing errors...

Comment: yes @Stackaccount1: he edited it after the fact. The original post was different. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: You confused `.address()` with `.address`. `address` exists only as a property of the signer an not as a method. The code is correct, you just got it confused on the last line

Comment: Great catch @BonisTech, I made the edit; yes indeed an oversight on the last line.